# Div active state not sticking onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a div which when clicked has another div underneath it slide up through a toggle and it can slide down if you click again. What ialso wanted to do is to add an `:active` state to the div button, so that it changes image when the opening div is toggled, however when you click on the div button you get a quick flash of the active state image and then it goes back to the default. For some reason the `:active` state is not sticking and i can't find why.

Here is the javascript

```
    $(function()
{

    $(".server_status_button").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if($(".server_status_button").is(":visible").length > 0){

            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
        else{

            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
        $("#status1").slideToggle();


    });

    $("#status1").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#status1").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

And here is the html for the whole thing

```
 <div id="server_status">
            <div class="server_status_button"></div><!---end server_status_button--->
            <div id="status1">
                <div class="status1_content" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">You are on:</div><!---end status1_content--->
                <div class="status1_content" style="font-size:12px;"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-color: #222;">Alnitak</span> - Status: <span style="color: #090;">Good</span></div><!---end status1_content--->
                <div class="status1_content"><span style="font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 10px;">1300/10000</span> Players</div><!---end status1_content--->
                <div class="status1_content_link" onclick="location.href='servers.php';">List Servers</div><!---end status1_content--->
            </div><!---end status1--->
        </div><!---end server_status--->
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:active` and adding a class `active` are 2 very different things. `:active` is pseudo-class added to an element whilst it is active (whilst the mouse is down). Whereas you are adding a normal css class `active`. You most likely have some css such as:

`.server_status_button:active { ... }`

If you change that to:

`.server_status_button.active { ... }`

then it should work.

Comment: ok great, that worked, when i clicked it the image changed to the active image, but when i click it again for it to go down, it slides down but the image does not change back to the default image, any ideas on what could be causing that?

Comment: I would say the if statement `if($(".server_status_button").is(":visible").length > 0)` is always true. Look into jQuery's hasClass function to figure out if the button is active.

Comment: Great, i solved it thanks to your help with `if($(".server_status_button").hasClass("active"))` Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

The `:active` CSS selector selects the element that is currently being clicked plus all of its ancestors. It only lasts as long as the mouse button is held down. What your code is doing is adding a class, which is selected using the subtly different `.active` in your CSS.